# RTSP Server for MJPEG

Tags: rtsp, rtp, mjpeg

I am working on a simple RTSP server to emulate an IP Camera but instead stream a jpeg image from a file.  I have been working through the rtsp protocol and cant find any specific data on what payload I should set in my DESCRIBE response.  Any good documentation would be appreciated

Thanks
Matt

Comment: cant you just use `rtsp://Location/Of/File` // `file://`... Also can you please add some code you have.. HArd to imagine what way you're approaching it.

Comment: I dont have much code to post yet but I am interfacing with an application that only supports the use of a proprietary OCX(intended to display IP Camera stream)to display changing graphics.  Listed supported formats are MPEG4 H264 and MJPEG.  I want to build a server that will just transmit a static jpeg like it was a MJPEG stream

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. It's the complete, official definition of RTSP:  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2326

Alternative, look at ffmpeg and/or VLC source code for a reference impl.

Btw, all this information can be obtained here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol

...which is the first link on google when you search RTSP.

Comment: I have looked through both those links.  My problem is none of it lists the AVP payloads specifically I cannot find the payload for MJPEG??

Answer (score 0):

The [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/rtp-parameters/rtp-parameters.xhtml#rtp-parameters-1) the lists RTP payload type 26 for JPEG.  You'll want to specify this in your media attribute of the SDP message in your response.  See [Appendix C.1.2 of the RTSP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2326#page-81) for information on media streams.  For additional information, see [section 8.1 of the SDP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4566#section-8.1).

An example would be:

```
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 26
```

Be sure to reference [RFC 2435](http://www.rfc-base.org/txt/rfc-2435.txt) for the RTP payload format that should be used for your RTP packets.